# Do I have the right idea for solving this 68-95-99.7 Empirical rule problem?

Tags: statistics

Question:
A bus driver drives the same route multiple times per day. The time it takes to complete one loop of the route follows a normal distribution with a mean of 54 minutes and standard deviation of 3 minutes. What is the probability it takes the driver more than 1 hour to complete one loop? (Use the Empirical Rule.)

My solution:
I am thinking here that if one standard deviation is 3 and the 68-95-99.7 rule states that 99.7% of all data falls within 3 standard deviations of the mean, then that would be 54 - (3)(3) for the negative side of the mean and 54 + (3)(3) for the positive side of the mean, so then the 63minutes would exceed the hour mark making the probability would be .997?

Thank you

Comment: A time of one hour is _two_ standard deviations above the mean. So there is roughly 5% probability that the time will be more than an hour or less than 48 min. Can you figure it out from there?

Comment: @bames but it says more than 1 hour. What am I getting mixed up here?

Comment: So it would be a .05 percent chance? because we know that two sd's hold 95% of the data as whatever is outside of that 95% is what the probability would be that it is going to be greater than an hour (the 95% range)

Comment: See Ross's response to your comment under his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like Bames suggests in the comments, $$54+2(3)=60$$ =1 hour, so that anything above 2 deviations above the mean takes more than one hour. You know $$50 $$% of values will always be below the mean of 54 mins. by symmetry. By the $$ 68-95-99.7$$ rule, $$95/2=47.5$$% of the data will fall two deviations above the mean. Now you have some $$2.5$$% left for the probability of being more than two deviations above the mean.

EDIT: Still, I do owe you something ;) , for posting the song, Foo. Assume you have the function $f$ that maps a $$z$$-value to $$(P: Z \leq z)$$. Then you want to  find $$ 1-f(2)$$

Answer (score 0):

You have three problems with your answer.  The times within three standard deviations of the mean are $45$ to $63$ minutes, which includes times both greater and less than one hour, so that is the wrong number of standard deviations to use.  The breakpoint of one hour is mean plus two standard deviations, so you want the chance the random variable is greater than mean plus two standard deviations.  The second problem is that you want the time outside the central peak.  Your intuition should tell you that the probability should be small the time is outside the peak, while $0.997$ is very close to $1$.  The rule says $0.95$ is within two standard deviations of the mean.  The third problem is you only want one side of the area outside two standard deviations, so need to divide by $2$.

Comment: Thanks. So if two sd's contains the data before it exceeds the one hour mark and that whole area underneath the curve contains 95% of the data, 95% is chance of that data occurring before the hour mark and the rest is the probability of the rest occurring outside the hour mark, therefore 5% or .05 ?

Comment: No, you missed the one sided nature of the question.  $95\%$ is within $2\sigma$, which is $48-60$ minutes.  Half of the rest is below $48$ minutes and you are asked for the amount above $60$.That was the third point.